# valid UUID is not a valid UUID

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework

I have a really weird problem were I'm getting that a valid UUID is not a valid UUID, for example:

```
'fd31b6b5-325d-4b65-b496-d7e4d16c8a93' is not a valid UUID.

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_db_prep_value
  2371.                 value = uuid.UUID(value)

File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/uuid.py" in __init__
  134.             hex = hex.replace('urn:', '').replace('uuid:', '')


      During handling of the above exception ('UUID' object has no attribute 'replace'), another exception occurred:
```

My models have an UUIDField as a pk, the error seems to happen randomly and won't dissapear until I restart the server, when the server restarts it works ok, so I'm a little lost here, I use django 1.10.7, postgresql 9.6.3, python 3.4.3 in amazon aws.

**Edit:**

Model causing trouble

```
class ReciboTransaccion(models.Model):    
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ingreso = models.ForeignKey('banco.BaseTransaccion', related_name='recibo_ingreso',
                                on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                null=True, blank=True,
                                editable=False)
    egreso = models.OneToOneField('banco.BaseTransaccion', related_name='recibo_egreso',
                                  on_delete=models.PROTECT,
                                  null=True, blank=True,
                                  editable=False)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The model 'BaseTransaccion' also has

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

**Edit 2:**

The code that triggers this error is the following

```
serial_movimientos = ReciboSerializer(recibos, many=True)

data = {
        'movimientos': serial_movimientos.data,  # Error happens here
    }
```

the serializer is pretty standard (serializer methods removed)

```
class ReciboSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingreso = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    egresos = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    descripcion = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    monedero_generado = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    reembolsada = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ReciboTransaccion
        fields = ('ingreso', 'egresos', 'descripcion', 'monedero_generado', 'reembolsada', 'fecha', )
```

The rest of the traceback is:

```
File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  42.             response = get_response(request)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/opt/python/current/app/myproject/main/ws.py" in index
  129.                 json_data = func(request)

File "/opt/python/current/app/myproject/main/ws.py" in get_datos_home
  534.         'movimientos': serial_movimientos.data,

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  739.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  263.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  657.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  256.         self._fetch_all()

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  1087.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __iter__
  54.         results = compiler.execute_sql()

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  824.             sql, params = self.as_sql()

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  376.             where, w_params = self.compile(self.where) if self.where is not None else ("", [])

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in compile
  353.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/where.py" in as_sql
  79.                 sql, params = compiler.compile(child)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in compile
  353.             sql, params = node.as_sql(self, self.connection)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in as_sql
  297.         return super(In, self).as_sql(compiler, connection)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in as_sql
  156.         rhs_sql, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in process_rhs
  284.             sqls, sqls_params = self.batch_process_rhs(compiler, connection, rhs)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in batch_process_rhs
  51.             _, params = self.get_db_prep_lookup(rhs, connection)

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in get_db_prep_lookup
  181.             if self.get_db_prep_lookup_value_is_iterable else

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py" in <listcomp>
  180.             [get_db_prep_value(v, connection, prepared=True) for v in value]

File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py" in get_db_prep_value
  2373.                 raise TypeError(self.error_messages['invalid'] % {'value': value})
```

Comment: Can you show us your model? Is the `UUIDField` the primary key?

Comment: This happens when you do something like `uuid.UUID(uuid.UUID('fd31b6b5-325d-4b65-b496-d7e4d16c8a93'))`. [`uuid.UUID()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID) doesn't support the case when its called with an argument that already is a UUID. Django catches [that case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#UUIDField), so something's fishy. Can you add some code that logs the of `value` just before the field conversion?

Comment: It's happening with a django rest framework serializer, what confuses me a lot is that the exact same code, and scenario works if I restart the server and some time later it happens againg and won't go away until I restart again

Comment: I'm at the exact same problem as Jorge Alfaro, restarting the server fixes the problem temporarily. And the problem started to happen randomly, my guess is that probably a library updated itself at some point.
I'm on python 2.7.12, AWS RDS PSQL 9.5.2, Django 1.11.4

Comment: Why are all the fields in the serializer of type [SerializerMethodField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)? wouldn't it make more sense to use [UUIDField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#uuidfield)? At least on the pure UUID ones

Comment: They have custom logic that returns other information not the uuid only

Comment: @JorgeAlfaro it looks like it fixed itself, is it fixed for you too? side-note: I am using AWS, elastic beanstalk to be precise.

Comment: Well it's been about 2 weeks since it last ocurred, as a side note I increased my instance from t2.small to t2.medium and changed from single instance to load balanced I don't know if that has anything to do with the problem not happening anymore

Comment: I had this occur in my test environment and am just as puzzled. I'm running Python 2.7.8, Django 1.9.13, and PostgreSQL 9.5. It started while the machine's memory was under contention (lots of swapping.) The issue didn't resolve itself. I had to restart the process to stop it.

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue and after restarting apache server it starts working smoothly.

Comment: this issue has resurfaced to me, do any of the guys having the same problem have more than one WSGIDaemonProcess ? for example for running two virtual hosts?

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same behavior as well. Django 2.1.5, DRF 3.9.1, PostgreSQL 10.6 on AWS. Deployed on elasticbeanstalk without a load balancer served by Apache. Anyone figured it out yet?

Comment: Found this answer because I was confused and upset with this exact same problem. Looking at the cause and proposed solution, I am now very confused, and very upset.

Comment: Is this issue solved for anyone of you? I have the exact problem. I tried almost every solution and added the solution from the answers to this thread. that is, WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}. Does this really solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Found a related [Django issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29293) and also [mod_wsgi issue](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/206).
For me, adding:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

to Apache config seems to have worked.

Comment: Is this really worked for you? I have the same issue with UUID.

Comment: @JintoAntony yeah, it worked. Check the two threads I linked, maybe there are more hints but basically only this line did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you read @Ivan's answer in which he identifies the specific Django issue that describes this problem.

For anyone who comes later (like me in a year or two), if you get the same problem with uwsgi, the solution is to modify the uwsgi.ini file in your Django project to include:

```
single-interpreter=true
```

for example your whole uwsgi.ini file might look like:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/opt/theapp/
module=yourdjangoproject.wsgi:application
mount=/secure/rest=yourdjangoproject.wsgi:application
home=/opt/theapp/venv3.8
processes=10
socket = 127.0.0.1:8000
single-interpreter=true
```