# Getting not not a valid UUID when I migrate in Django

Tags: python, django

I added a field called transaction_id in my models.py I want that field to be used to track every transaction on my **DuesLevy** model I imported uuid for this to happen, but each time I migrate I get this error.
How do i prevent this error from occurring each time I migrate (python manage.py migrate)

```
 "C:\Users\Benedict\Miniconda3\envs\django3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2344, in to_python
params={'value': value},
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'13615773708697' is not a valid UUID."]
```

This issue have been reported [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45990550/valid-uuid-is-not-a-valid-uuid) but seems no solution yet. 
I am using Django 3 + MySQL
**models.py**

```
trans_id = uuid.uuid4()
trans_str = trans_id.int
pass_trans = str(trans_str)[:12]
class DuesLevy(models.Model):
    class_of_dues = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=options.CHOOSE, choices=options.CLASS_OF_DUES, blank=True)
    payment_circle = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=options.CHOOSE, choices=options.PAYMENT_CIRCLE)
    payment_option = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=options.CHOOSE, choices=options.PAYMENT_OPTION)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    transaction_id = models.UUIDField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, editable=False, default=pass_trans)
    payment_channel = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=options.CHOOSE, choices=options.PAYMENT_CHANNEL_TYPE)
    payment_date = models.DateField()
    date_recorded = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.amount


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('backend:detail_dues', kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen? You pass 12 characters int as an uuid, which is not a valid uuid.

Comment: I want to shorten the characters to 12, can't I do that, let me try it with full characters

Comment: Just pass `default=uuid.uuid4` and you will be both safe and good to go (instead of `default=pass_trans` ).

Comment: I am still getting the same error after passing default=uuid.uuid4, can't I shorten the value to the length I want?

Comment: No, that wouldn't be an uuid.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to the `default` argument of `models.UUIDField`. `uuid.uuid4` is a function that when called, returns a new uuid object. Don't pass string or integer as a default argument.

If you want to dig into the source code, here's how the internals of a `Field` work.
[https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py#L827](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L827)

Comment: I created a function and pass it to the 'default' argument but still getting the same error

Comment: The link is quite a handful don't know where to start

Comment: You don't need to browse through this link. You don't need to create your own function. Passing `default=uuid.uuid4` is all you need. If it doesn't work, then there's something wrong with your migration/state of db. What's the exception?

Comment: Thanks for your reply it worked like you said I deleted my migration files and delete my database then passed `default=uuid.uuid4.int` in field since I want it as integer it worked.

Comment: But what I wanted was a 12 digit number after making some research I found out that it is not proper to limit the length of UUID. The process of doing that caused my issues. so to achieve a random 12 digit number I had to import `from random import randint`

Comment: Then passed this as an option `default = randint(100000000000, 999999999999)` in my field

Comment: Well, if you want to store a random int then you might be better off with `BigIntegerField`.

Comment: Thanks for ur response